# How to link a prebuilt shared Library to an Android NDK project?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

Here I used this `Android.mk` file in `jni/` folder.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Here we give our module name and source file(s)
LOCAL_MODULE    := offlineDownload
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := offline_download.c

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES :=../lib/libpackext.so.1.0
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And make one `lib` folder in project directory and put my prebuilt `.so` library and make one `Android.mk` file which contains following

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := packext
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libpackext.so.1.0
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And when i use `ndk-build -B` command than i got *undefined reference to packageExtraction*. Here I use my prebuilt library functions means I can't link my prebuilt shared library to my `offlinedownload` library.

So any body please help me to solved out this issue.

Comment: Can you please explain your question in detail?

Answer (score 37):

Here is a complete Android.mk file for using a 3rd party shared library.
The library (libffmpeg.so) is placed in the jni folder.
Its "LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES" specifies where the header files are kept for the library.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ffmpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libffmpeg.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../ffmpeg/libs/arm-linux-androideabi4.7_1/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ffmpegandroid
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpegandroid.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := ffmpeg
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

If you wanted to support multiple architectures then you could specify:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 mips
```

in your jni/Application.mk and change the LOCAL_SRC_FILES to something like:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libffmpeg.so
```

and place a libffmpeg.so at jni/armeabi/libffmpeg.so, jni/armeabi-v7a/libffmpeg.so etc ..

Comment: Why the libffmpeg.so need to be in jni folder? With all the architectures, how to make it easier?

Comment: I modified the example to show how to support multiple architectures.

Comment: it's also possible to put the external libs in `jniLibs/...` and use: `LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ..\jniLibs\$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)\libffmpeg.so`

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/danbrough/andrudio for an example of compiling ffmpeg (or libav) for android.

Comment: Where should add shared library finally?! PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY ? LOCAL_JNI_SHARED_LIBRARIES ? LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES ?

Comment: Thank you! Hard to find examples for this that actually have a complete Android.mk with multiple entries.

Answer (score 9):

**Android NDK official `hello-libs` CMake example**

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/840858984e1bb8a7fab37c1b7c571efbe7d6eb75/hello-libs

Just worked for me on Ubuntu 17.10 host, Android Studio 3, Android SDK 26, NDK 15.2. so I strongly recommend that you base your project on it.

The shared library is called `libgperf`, the key code parts are:

- [hello-libs/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/840858984e1bb8a7fab37c1b7c571efbe7d6eb75/hello-libs/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt):

  ```
  // -L
  add_library(lib_gperf SHARED IMPORTED)
  set_target_properties(lib_gperf PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
            ${distribution_DIR}/gperf/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libgperf.so)

  // -I
  target_include_directories(hello-libs PRIVATE
                             ${distribution_DIR}/gperf/include)
  // -lgperf
  target_link_libraries(hello-libs
                        lib_gperf)
  ```
- on C++ code, use: `#include <gperf.h>`
- header location: `hello-libs/distribution/gperf/include/gperf.h`
- lib location: `distribution/gperf/lib/arm64-v8a/libgperf.so`
- [app/build.gradle](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/840858984e1bb8a7fab37c1b7c571efbe7d6eb75/hello-libs/app/build.gradle):

  ```
  android {
      sourceSets {
          main {
              // let gradle pack the shared library into apk
              jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../distribution/gperf/lib']
  ```

  Then, if you look under `/data/app` on the device, `libgperf.so` will be there as well.
- If you only support some architectures, see: [Gradle Build NDK target only ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278152/gradle-build-ndk-target-only-arm/47558314#47558314)

The example git tracks the prebuilt shared libraries, but it also contains the build system to actually build them as well: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/840858984e1bb8a7fab37c1b7c571efbe7d6eb75/hello-libs/gen-libs

Answer (score 2):

You have to do either one of the following:

1. Cut and paste everything except LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) from your second Android.mk into your first.
2. Put the following in the end of your first Android.mk:

   $(call import-module,packext)

   Also make sure that you set your NDK_MODULE_PATH environment variable to a path where the Android.mk-file defining the module packext can be found.

You also have to change the LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES in the same way mgiza said in the first answer. I suppose the packageExtraction that you got undefined reference to is in your prebuilt library so unless you have other linking problems this should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the ndk documentation for prebuilts:

android-ndk/docs/PREBUILTS.html

You have to change

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES :=../lib/libpackext.so.1.0
```

to

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := packext
```

Be sure that your folder containing the Android.mk for the packext module is named packext and can be found in in your NDK_MODULE_PATH.

Comment: Here i put my Android.mk and libpackext.so.1.0 in lib folder .this lib folder is in project directory path.where i make jni folder