# Compile native C++ shared object with Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have generated a `.so` file via C++ on Linus and got `.so` file generated now I have cross compile this `.so` file for `Android ARM` so I have to comiple it via `Android NDK` so that new genrated `.so`
can be used in my android project .

So can anyone help me where I have to put Linux generated .so file in my Android project and what to add in Make file(Android.mk) so that it can generate new `.so` file with existing methods in my previous Linux generated `.so` file.

I hope my question is clear to you all, if not please tell me.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? If so, did you enable native project support (Its been a while, but I think that's what its called)? You will need to use both `Application.mk` and `Android.mk`, though, if its Eclipse.

Comment: yes I am using eclipse and I took help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870435/how-can-i-link-prebuilt-shared-library-to-android-ndk-project but I am getting .so file format is not recognized, I have Android.mk file in my android project and also i have enabled NDK support

Comment: You don't cross-compile an .so file. You cross-compile its _source code_.

Comment: but i have no idea how to cross compile source code .is it not possible to cross compile .so file

Comment: The .so file contains machine code for the system you compile it for. You need to cross compile that, just the same way you would if you wanted to create a native executable. If you don't know/understand how to do that, you will need to look up how to cross compile for android in general.

Comment: @SNDel - You seem to be lacking some critical concepts. You should probably pick up a book on native Android development. This is a pretty good one: [Android Native Development Kit Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/android-native-development-kit-cookbook).

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps to build a native C++ shared object.

1. Add native support to your project. See Android's [Add native support](http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin)
2. Add your C++ files to the JNI folder
3. Create an `Android.mk`, add it to the the JNI folder, and add the architectures you want to support. For example:

   ```
   APP_ABI   := armeabi x86 mips armeabi-v7a
   ```

4. Pick a C++ runtime library. See the CPLUSPLUS.README in the NDK. I picked STL Port for the runtime (the GNU runtime was toxic due to its license).
5. Create an `Appication.mk`, add it to the the JNI folder, and add the magic. For example:

   ```
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

   # NDK_DEBUG_IMPORTS := 1

   #########################################################
   # STLport library
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   STLPORT_INCL     := /opt/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport
   STLPORT_LIB      := /opt/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)

   LOCAL_MODULE := stlport_shared
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(STLPORT_LIB)/libstlport_shared.so

   LOCAL_EXPORT_CPPFLAGS :=
   LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(STLPORT_INCL)

   include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

   LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES  := stlport_shared

   #########################################################
   # Crypto++ library
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   CRYPTOPP_INCL   := /usr/local/cryptopp/android-$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/include
   CRYPTOPP_LIB    := /usr/local/cryptopp/android-$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib

   LOCAL_MODULE       := cryptopp
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES    := $(CRYPTOPP_LIB)/libcryptopp.so

   LOCAL_EXPORT_CPPFLAGS := -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function
   LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(CRYPTOPP_INCL) $(CRYPTOPP_INCL)/cryptopp

   include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

   LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES  := cryptopp

   #########################################################
   # PRNG library
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   APP_STL         := stlport_shared
   APP_MODULES     := prng stlport_shared cryptopp

   # My ass... LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES is useless
   LOCAL_C_INCLUDES   := $(STLPORT_INCL) $(CRYPTOPP_INCL)

   LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES := rtti exceptions

   LOCAL_CPP_FLAGS    := -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function
   LOCAL_CPP_FLAGS    += -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL

   LOCAL_LDLIBS            := -llog -landroid
   LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES  := cryptopp stlport_shared

   LOCAL_MODULE    := prng
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libprng.cpp

   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
   ```

My library depends on STLport. The stuff following *"STLport library"* ensures my library is compiled against `stlport_shared.so`, and the `stlport_shared.so` is copied into the APK.

My library also depends upon a [cross-compiled version of Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_%28Command_Line%29). Crypto++ was also compiled/linked against `stlport_shared.so`. The stuff following *"Crypto++ library"* ensures my library is compiled against `libcryptopp.so`, and the `libcryptopp.so` is copied into the APK.

Finally, my library is called out. My library is the stuff following *"PRNG library"* (its a one file test project). It builds `libprng.so`, and ensures `libprng.so` is copied into the APK.

You'll also need Android classes. Here's what mine looks like.

```
package com.cryptopp.prng;

public class PRNG {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("stlport_shared");
        System.loadLibrary("cryptopp");
        System.loadLibrary("prng");
    }

    private static native int CryptoPP_Reseed(byte[] bytes);

    private static native int CryptoPP_GetBytes(byte[] bytes);

    private static Object lock = new Object();

    // Class method. Returns the number of bytes consumed from the seed.
    public static int Reseed(byte[] seed) {         
        synchronized (lock) {
            return CryptoPP_Reseed(seed);
        }
    }

    // Class method. Returns the number of bytes generated.
    public static int GetBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return CryptoPP_GetBytes(bytes);
        }
    }

    // Instance method. Returns the number of bytes consumed from the seed.
    public int reseed(byte[] seed) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return CryptoPP_Reseed(seed);
        }
    }

    // Instance method. Returns the number of bytes generated.
    public int getBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return CryptoPP_GetBytes(bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

The Android modified build system really sucks. Its sufficiently different from standard make-based projects and poorly documented. But that's what Android offers, so that's what you have to use. Eclipse's Android native support is built around it.

---

If interested, here's what the wrapper header file looks like. You can use `javah` to generate it from your DEX file (compiled Java classes).

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_cryptopp_prng_PRNG */

#ifndef _Included_com_cryptopp_prng_PRNG
#define _Included_com_cryptopp_prng_PRNG
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_cryptopp_prng_PRNG
 * Method:    CryptoPP_Reseed
 * Signature: ([B)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_cryptopp_prng_PRNG_CryptoPP_1Reseed
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jbyteArray);

/*
 * Class:     com_cryptopp_prng_PRNG
 * Method:    CryptoPP_GetBytes
 * Signature: ([B)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_cryptopp_prng_PRNG_CryptoPP_1GetBytes
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jbyteArray);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: I got help via this post and total code and flow i used...So its helpful

Comment: @Neha Shukla, How to compile .so file from command prompt only?