# Android NDK including a 3rd party prebuilt shared library with Gradle and CMake

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake, android-gradle-plugin

I'm struggling to include a prebuilt shared library in my android project

The library in question is libusb, which the NDK part of my android project requires.

Everything is compiling and linking OK, i.e. the project is building successfully, but on installing the apk on my device the app is crashing.

The relevant error msg from monitor is:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libusb1.0.so" not found
```

what i've tried so far is adding the following to my app/build.gradle:

```
sourceSets{
    main {
        // let gradle pack the shared library into apk
        jniLibs.srcDirs = '/home/me/third-party/libusb-1.0.21/android/libs/'
    }
```

in CMakeLists.txt i've added:

```
set(libusb_DIR $ENV{HOME}/third-party/libusb-1.0.21/android/libs)
set(libusb_LIB usb1.0)

link_directories( ${libusb_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/ )
target_link_libraries( ${libusb_LIB} )
```

I've even tried creating a `app/src/main/jniLibs` dir and manually copying the armeabi-v7a version of the shared lib, `libusb1.0.so`, in there.

Still getting same error message in Monitor after the apk has been installed..

Comment: You should check if `libusb1.0.so` is packed into the APK. Android Studio provides a tool to analyse the APK and see its contents.

Comment: I have shown how to do it at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870435/how-to-link-a-prebuilt-shared-library-to-an-android-ndk-project/47558694#47558694 I had answered here but it was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to this one, instead of taking the path from env you should try ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}

```
set(usb_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../libs)
add_library(libusb SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libusb PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${usb_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libusb1.0.so)

target_link_libraries(${libusb})
```